# How can I reattach the wire that locks the D500 focus screen in place?

Tags: nikon, dslr, repair, focusing-screen

The piece of wire that locks the focusing screen of my Nikon D500 has come loose completely. I cannot figure out where the two loops of the wire reattach, and I was wondering if this is an easy fix that I can do at home?

I am fairly new to the internal mechanisms of DSLRs so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

Comment: http://www.focusingscreen.com/work/d800en.htm

Comment: http://deanmalandris.com/D70_technical/Cleaning%20the%20focusing%20screen/index.php

Comment: Thanks for the pictures. In my case the wire lock has completely detached from the camera body (in the pictures the wire locks still seem to be hinged inside the camera somewhere).

Comment: Yeah, and those photos should clue you in to approximately where the attachment points are... now get a small mirror (like a dentist would use) and look indie there until you find them.